# Portal row editable fields acting strange when in focus (FileMaker Pro 18)

Tags: layout, filemaker

Not entirely sure the best way to describe this strange behavior that I've been dealing with, so I've added screenshots below. Anyway, I've built portals inside of a tab control field on my layout. Initially, my fields inside of the portal would turn fully black whenever I scrolled through the records or tried to make edits to the field itself. However, after changing from the Classic Theme the file is currently using, it's stopped completely filling in black, but the fields are still showing some strange behavior.

Basically, even though I've made sure every possible alteration of the field (active, in focus, hover, etc) all have the exact same styling on them, the entire set of fields get this weird outline on them when I go to edit a single field.

[image: Nothing selected here, this is how I'd like the portal to stay whether someone is making changes or not.]
Nothing selected here, this is how I'd like the portal to stay whether someone is making changes or not.

[image: The "NRG" field is selected to make changes, and every other field ends up getting a strange border around the field.]
The "NRG" field is selected to make changes, and every other field ends up getting a strange border around the field.

Any help that you might have in getting rid of this strange behavior would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY.

Found the answer. Evidently there is a check box in the Layout Setup menu for "Show Field Frames when record is active."

Uncheck that.

Fixed.